# Server principal error in Stored Procedure, while ignoring database specified in USE

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an error:

> The server principal 'USER1' is not able to access the DB2 database under the current security context.

```
USE [DB1]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Proc1] 
With execute as 'User1'
as 
Select * from Table1
```

The procedure is simple as rock, as can be seen, but for some reason, I receive an error that USER1 doesn't have access to completely different DB2. It makes no sense. Table1 - is located in DB1, the procedure is stored there as well. User1 has credentials to access DB2 too, but it's not even needed. Any ideas what can cause that, and how to fix it?

Comment: Ah, yes, that i replaced original user name with that placeholder.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like an "is this thing plugged in" error. Verify you're looking at the correct server in all cases, do a `select * from sys.tables where name = 'Table1'` to verify that your info about `Table1` is indeed correct (and it's not, say, a view or synonym) and last but not least check for database or server-level DDL triggers that aren't properly written.

Comment: Database is correct, i've checked select part, each table and user name and permissions set. Tried to change user for other - still the same message. And as for DDL triggers - there's only one for that DB - audit. So it shouldn't affect the procedure.

Comment: To clarify, do you get the error when the procedure is *created*, or when it's *executed*? In the former case a trigger is almost certainly the guilty party (of course the *number* of triggers is irrelevant, it's about what the trigger actually contains). In the latter case it's not.

Comment: On execution. This procedure exists for quite long time and stopped working just recently.

Comment: Quite the mystery then. The only thing I can think of is hitting it with an `sp_recompile`. Beyond that I suspect the example as it is is oversimplified and we'd need more details on the actual DBs and setup, but I can't think of a targeted question at the moment. If all else fails you could try recreating the user and associated procedures, if that doesn't break things too severely. If it does then trying to replicate things on another server and comparing differences may be the only way.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `sp_refreshsqlmodule` -- I *think* `sp_recompile` implies a refresh as well for sprocs but I'm not sure and I'm too lazy to check.